# Create a copy of .mdf with a different name

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I have a `.mdf` file in SQL Server 2017 Express, eg `Myfirst.mdf`.

I want to use this as a template for another database; how to create a copy of a `.mdf` using vb6 code.

Comment: Script the database instead. Extract the current schema using scripting tools and bundle those into your program. It should give little problem. Copying the .mdf is just asking for trouble, not to mention carrying all the data along with you.

Comment: Thanks i agree with you.  What scripting tools do your recommend.  Can i script an mdb.

Comment: What is your opinion of SSMS. It appears this is an Add-In in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and i seem to to see it as a function in SSMS17.

Using this function a script a my.mdf to my.sql.  Now i want to use this in a script to alter already create new.mdf.  Perhaps lead me to some where to read existing knowledge base.

Comment: Just the default SSMS is enough to get started, no addin is needed. Select the database and the context menu go to tasks => generate scripts and that will guide though scripting any object you need, plus the data if you really want.

Comment: Alejandro  THANK YOU AGAIN